# IndexError: list index out of range, scores.append( (fields[0], fields[1]))

Tags: python-3.4

I'm trying to read a file and put contents in a list. I have done this mnay times before and it has worked but this time it throws back the error "list index out of range".

the code is:

```
with open("File.txt") as f:
scores = []
for line in f:
    fields = line.split()
    scores.append( (fields[0], fields[1])) 
    print(scores)
```

The text file is in the format;

```
Alpha:[0, 1]
Bravo:[0, 0]
Charlie:[60, 8, 901]
Foxtrot:[0]
```

I cant see why it is giving me this problem. Is it because I have more than one value for each item? Or is it the fact that I have a colon in my text file?

How can I get around this problem?

Thanks

Comment: What you want to store in scores?

Comment: the contents of the text file in format of-  score : name. So for example once I print(scores) it should give an output like:    60 : Charlie    etc.

Comment: But what if many have the same score?

Comment: It would probably be better to print: Charlie : 60. But I still get same error.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well this code will print you desired result:

```
import re

with open("File.txt") as f:
    # Let's make dictionary for scores {name:scores}.
    scores = {}

    # Define regular expressin to parse team name and team scores from line.
    patternScore = '\[([^\]]+)\]'
    patternName = '(.*):'

    for line in f:
        # Find value for team name and its scores.
        fields = re.search(patternScore, line).groups()[0].split(', ')
        name = re.search(patternName, line).groups()[0]

        # Update dictionary with new value.
        scores[name] = fields 

    # Print output first goes first element of keyValue in dict then goes keyName
    for key in scores:
        print (scores[key][0] + ':' + key)
```

You will recieve following output:

```
60:Charlie
0:Alpha
0:Bravo
0:Foxtrot
```